# Colorbox appears to be breaking <a href="mailto:"> @ symbols...any ideas?

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, colorbox, mailto

I am having a strange issue with the colorbox jQuery plugin and need some guidance.

The plugin is working fine and loads an external html file when clicked. The external html file loads in the colorbox modal window fine but has only one problem...

This line of code;

```
<p>Email: <a class="email" href="mailto:name@company.com">name@company.com</a></p>
```

For whatever reason no matter whether the mailto has an @ symbol or the html number equivalent it is always rendered on the front end as & #64; in flat text. Thus, when a user clicks/copies the link it displays as name& #64;company.com

Any ideas how to get around this?

It doesn't seem like a common problem on the colorbox site and I can't find any other mention of an issue like this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated,

Andy

Comment: have you tried "mailto:name&amp;company.com"? (maybe idk :P)

Answer (score 1):

I can't repro the problem here using a similar setup using ColorBox's **iframe** option.

You might consider verifying the DocType of the parent file and/or loading the child page (the one with the mail-to) straight into a browser.

That will isolate whether ColorBox is involved or not... but you knew that, I bet.

Regards

- Kevin M.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably an issue relating to your CMS, and not something specific to using colorbox.  Pull up your JS console and make an ajax request from your server and see what it returns to you.  My guess is that the encoding is happening on the server-side before the markup ever reaches colorbox.